# Recommended fit/tolreance for multipeice crankshaft sections

Tags: gears, machining, tolerance

I am designing a machine that will feature a multi-piece crankshaft. The crankshaft sections will come apart in order to slide the crankshaft through some mounted ball bearings. The fit I am aiming for is similar to the fit of a drive sprocket on a shaft. The flat crankshaft sections will slip onto the shaft sections and be secured by a bolt and two keyways.

After doing some research on wikipedia, I found the following fit:

Similar fit - Negligible clearance or interference fit which can be assembled or disassembled with a rubber mallet, e.g., hubs, gears, pulleys, bushes, bearings  - H7/j6

I am also considering an H7/k6

This fit sounds like a good choice for a crankshaft section, since a gear or pulley must transmit power/torque in a similar fashion.

[image: Here are some pictures of my system]

[image]